# How to formulate this SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Retail`

```
CustomerID       Itemset
    1              31
    1              30 
    1              78
    2              31
    2              91
    3              30
    3              31
```

I want to to find the count of `CustomerID` having both `30` & `31` in `Itemset`. 
I.e. In this case `1` & `3`, so the count is `2`.

I tried formulating the query using the `&` operator but the query isn't returning the right answer.

my query- `Select count(customerID) from Retail where Itemset=30 & 31`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select count(*)
from
(
    select CustomerId
    from Retail
    where Itemset in (30,31)
    group by CustomerId
    having count(distinct Itemset) = 2   -- this guarantees that CustomerId have at least one 30 and at least one 31 in column Itemset 
) T
```

Comment: @ash Thank You so much. Sorry for the late feedback. 
What if I want compare 3 values (30,31,71) then what changes in the query will I have to do?

Comment: @Api, 1st: where Itemset in (30,31,71); 2nd: having count(distinct Itemset) = 3

Answer (score 2):

```
Select count(distinct(CustomerID))  from (
    select r30.CustomerID
    from Retail r30
    inner join Retail r31 on
    r31.CustomerID = r30.CustomerID
    where 
    r30.Itemset = 30 
    and r31.Itemset = 31
) T
```

Comment: This also give the right answer (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a955e/6) - that is when you fix your 2 syntax errors (missing close `)` and missing table alias ).

Answer (score 0):

You only want to count the distinct CustomerID's.... I haven't tested this, but believe this is the way to go...

```
Select count( distinct customerID)
from Retail
where Itemset in (30,31)
```

--- This was wrong... after a little tinkering, I came to the already provided solution... please disregard....

```
 Select count(*)
 from (
       Select CustomerID
       from Retail
       where Itemset in (30,31)
       group by CustomerID
       having count(CustomerID = 2)
  ) T
```

--- Kudos.  This assumes that CustomerID and Itemset cannot have duplicates. In other words, it assumes you wouldn't have two or more rows with 1,30 for CustomerID and Itemset.

Comment: This is the same as my (now deleted) answer. Deleted because it gives the answer `3` not `2` as the OP requests. You see this will return all 3 customers, but only 2 of them have ItemSet 30 & Itemset 31.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @Jamiec ... I corrected my solution, as I tested it and gave a slightly different version, but I believe the same conclusion... if I missed something, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
select CustomerID,count(*)  from [dbo].[Retail] where Itemset in(30,31)
group by CustomerID
```

If you want only the count result then use [Common Table Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175972.aspx)

like this:

```
;with cte1
as
(select CustomerID,count(*) as rs  from [dbo].[Retail] where Itemset in(30,31)
    group by CustomerID
)
select rs from cte1
```